# MongoError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or mult

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a document using two parallel multi-document transactions and I get the following error:
‍‍‍

```
MongoError: WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use withTransaction api.

Comment: @D.SM. Thank you for your comment. Can you please provide a link to a source or doc that I can figure it out?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/transactions/

Comment: @D.SM: That didn't help!

Comment: For future reference, check whether you ended the session or not.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a code snippet where you are updating these documents? You might be missing an `await` or you might not be ending your session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WriteConflicts occur in mongodb when two or more write operations try to modify a document at the same time. Since mongodb uses optimistic concurrency control, it fails the latter operation and retries the latter write operation internally.

Transactions in mongodb can be implemented in 2 ways:

1. **Core api** - the retry logic is not implemented internally but rather left for the developers to incorporate
2. **Callback api** - the retry logic is already incorporated

I believe you are using the core api approach and that's why it is giving this error. Try switching to callback api approach to solve it.

Comment: Refer these for further clarification - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-in-applications/  and  https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/mongodb-transaction-management-884f82f62767